# SEO: Similar Title & H1 wording across most pages on a site

Tags: seo

On a site that sells electronics, suppose the Title and H1 tag of every category page contained the words "Shop for" followed by the category. 
IE the page that pertained to laptops would have in its tags:

```
<title> Shop for Laptops </title>
<h1> Shop for Laptops <h1>
```

...and the page that pertained to cameras would have in its tags:

```
<title> Shop for Cameras </title>
<h1> Shop for Cameras <h1>
```

// etc..

Would the fact that "Shop for" was in the title and H1 tag of every category page hinder SEO? Would it be better if there was some variance to the words "Shop for" across the site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: It's not going to make a difference. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Are SEO posts not allowed? If so, my apologies as I was not aware of that!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about computer programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO and not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

The right format for title is "The most important keyword | 2nd  important keyword | 3rd  important keyword". For example, if we want to sell a camera, we can set the title for the page - "Canon EOS 5D Mark III - SLR Camera - Your Website Name". "Canon EOS 5D Mark III" is the product name, "SLR Camera" is the category name, and the 3rd  important keyword is your website name. In addition, we use symbols "-" or "|" to divide the keywords. Last, remove the words that users do not search from search engines, eg, "search for".

Answer (score -1):

Yea I am agree with @Cythilya

That is good and title should be like this

"The most important keyword | 2nd important keyword | 3rd important keyword"